# I created a virtual environment in my editor but when I wanted to activate it by this code (kivy_venv/Scripts/activate) editor gave me error message

Tags: python, virtual-environment

The error message was ( cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see
"get-help about_signing" for more details )

Can you help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an error of Powershell.

It should work if you just use the CMD instead.

If you want to stick with Powershell, then you can try to disable the restriction with `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` (Powershell has to be run as Administrator)